# larave api response show in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, api

How can I show JSON response in foreach loop:

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->get('https://api.exchangerate.host/symbols');
$data['symbols'] = $res->getBody();

return view('welcome', $data);
```

When I tried to show using loop then showing nothing
Here is my loop

```
@foreach ($symbols as $symbol)
    <a href="" onclick="myfunction()">{{ $symbol }}</a>
@endforeach
```

And here is the response code

```
{
    "motd": {
        "msg": "If you or your company use this project or like what we doing, please consider backing us so we can continue maintaining and evolving this project.",
        "url": "https://exchangerate.host/#/donate"
    },
    "success": true,
    "symbols": {
        "AED": {
            "description": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
            "code": "AED"
        },
        "AFN": {
            "description": "Afghan Afghani",
            "code": "AFN"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show just symbols in the loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json response should be decoded.

Try this

```
$data['symbols'] = json_decode($res->getBody())->symbols;
```

```
@foreach ($symbols as $symbol)
    <a href="" onclick="myfunction()">{{ $symbol['code'] }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: showing now Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in

Comment: @MDMasum can you post complete error message? which line of code has this error?

Comment: $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->get('https://api.exchangerate.host/symbols');
        return $data['symbols'] = json_decode($res->getBody())->symbols;  showing me this error Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in

Comment: aah, that's different error.
do, $data['symbols'] = json_decode($res->getBody())->symbols; return $data['symbols'];

Comment: or, like this
return json_decode($res->getBody(), true)['symbols'];

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the correct information into the `$data` variable. Change from this

```
$data['symbols'] = $res->getBody();
```

to this

```
$data['symbols'] = $res->getBody()->symbols;
```

You also need to change the `foreach` loop as follows :-

```
@foreach ($symbols as $symbol)
    <a href="" onclick="myfunction()">{{ $symbol['code'] }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you will walsh, but getting this Cannot use object of type GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream as array error now

Comment: @MDMasum check the edit. I mistook the response body as an array rather than the GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream object.

Answer (score 0):

If JSON response is coming from the API, you can use PHP function json_decode() to decode. Here is the manual for the function.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php